# Appending an int key in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, integer

I am trying to create a dictionary from the following lists:

```
link_i = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
link_j = [2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4]

link_i = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
link_j = [2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4]
nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Creating a dictionary containing nodes and their incoming links:
out_dict =  {}
for i in nodes:
    for j in range(0,len(link_i)):
        if (link_i[j] == i):
            if i not in out_dict:
                out_dict[i] = link_j[j]
            elif i in out_dict:
               out_dict[i].append(link_j[j])
```

However, I am not able to append the key since it has the type int. I get the error:

```
line 21, in <module>
    out_dict[i].append(link_j[j])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am trying to get the output as:

```
{1: [2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 5], 4: [5, 6], 5: [6, 4], 6: [4]}
```

Comment: Well, `out_dict[i].append(link_j[j])` is definitely incorrect. I guess it should be `out_dict.append(i, link_j[j])`.

Comment: But out_dict is a dictionary and then you'll get ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that – I'm not an expert in Python. According to section 5.5 of https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html , `out_dict[i] = link_j[j]` could work.

Comment: Hello, this works in the first if loop when i is not a key to the dictionary. When it's already a key, instead of appending, it replaces the value with a new value. I want both the values for the key. This is what I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if i not in out_dict:
    out_dict[i] = link_j[j]
```

to

```
if i not in out_dict:
    out_dict[i] = [link_j[j]]
```

This is because after you first add key "i" to out_dict, you are assigning it a single value which is of type int. In order to be able to add to this, later on, it needs to be a mutatable data type such as a list which does have attribute append. This doesn't fix all your problems because even with this change you still don't get your desired output but it will allow you to debug further.

Comment: yes, this solves the error and I think the problem should be in the loops but I get a dictionary with some values right now and I can work further. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Hope you work out the looping

Answer (score 2):

To keep the code simple you can use a dict [comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and set the default value for each node to empty list. With that you don't need to check if the node is already part of the dict and you can just append the links.

```py
link_i = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
link_j = [2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4]
nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Creating a dictionary containing nodes and their incoming links:
# fill the dict with empty lists for each node
out_dict =  {node: [] for node in nodes}
for i in nodes:
    for j in range(0,len(link_i)):
        if (link_i[j] == i):
            # append link to the list for the node
            out_dict[i].append(link_j[j])
```

The output then looks like this:

```py
{1: [2, 3], 2: [], 3: [1, 2, 5], 4: [5, 6], 5: [6, 4], 6: [4]}
```

Comment: This also helps in printing an empty list for node 2, since the node has zero links. This really helps. Thank you.